# Generate Crystal Reports using SQL queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, crystal-reports

I am using **Crystal Report 8.0.1.0.**

I want to generate some reports based on some SQL queries on a particular DB.

Please can you tell me how to do this?

Comment: Havenot yet tried.need guidance on how to go about it and make a start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Make a data connection to the required database in crystal report.
2. Open the command and paste your query there and click ok.
3. Now go to the design and place the fields and create required report.

Let me know if you need further guidance

Comment: I am unable to find the command part where i can write my query. I am only arriving at the design part and the report template is being shown.

Comment: There will be `Add Command` double click on that and paste command there

Comment: That is a wierd thing happening that Add Command is not coming. Can any settings issue cause that to happen?

Comment: can you paste a screeshot of window after making database connection?

Comment: Great.....you can accept it as answer..so that others can use